# ClassCastException in Android RecyclerAdapter

Tags: java, android, classcastexception, android-recyclerview

I'm having a very difficult time understanding why I'm getting a ClassCastException in my RecyclerAdapter class. I have set it up to accept two different types of views, one for regular feed items and the other for native advertisements. What is going wrong?

**In my main activity, I call my constructor as follows:**

```
feedItems = new ArrayList<>();
List<Feed> adItems = new ArrayList<>();
recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
marketFeedRecyclerAdapter = new MarketFeedRecyclerAdapter(this, feedItems, new ImageLoader(new FeedItemFileCache(this)), adItems);
```

**I get a complaint at this line in my RecyclerAdapter class, with the stack trace to follow:**

```
bindAdItemView((AdViewHolder) viewHolder);
```

**My stack trace:**

> ```
> java.lang.ClassCastException: 
> com.elgami.utility.LoadingRowRecyclerAdapter$LoadingViewHolder cannot be cast to com.elgami.market.MarketFeedRecyclerAdapter$AdViewHolder
> at com.elgami.market.MarketFeedRecyclerAdapter.onBindViewHolder(MarketFeedRecyclerAdapter.java:80)
> at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:5768)
> at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.bindViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:5801)
> at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:5037)
> at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:4913)
> at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager$LayoutState.next(LinearLayoutManager.java:2029)
> at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.layoutChunk(LinearLayoutManager.java:1414)
> at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.fill(LinearLayoutManager.java:1377)
> at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.onLayoutChildren(LinearLayoutManager.java:578)
> at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayoutStep2(RecyclerView.java:3260)
> at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayout(RecyclerView.java:3069)
> at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.onLayout(RecyclerView.java:3518)
> at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16636)
> at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5437)
> at android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout.onLayout(SwipeRefreshLayout.java:598)
> at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16636)
> at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5437)
> at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1743)
> at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1586)
> at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1495)
> at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16636)
> at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onLayout(RelativeLayout.java:1079)
> at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16636)
> at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5437)
> at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:336)
> at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:273)
> at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16636)
> at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5437)
> at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1743)
> at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1586)
> at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1495)
> at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16636)
> at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5437)
> at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:336)
> at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:273)
> at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16636)
> at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5437)
> at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1743)
> at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1586)
> at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1495)
> at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16636)
> at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5437)
> at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:336)
> at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:273)
> at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onLayout(PhoneWindow.java:2678)
> at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16636)
> at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5437)
> at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:2171)
> at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1931)
> at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1107)
> at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6013)
> at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:858)
> at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:670)
> at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:606)
> at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:844)
> at an
> ```

**The following is my RecyclerAdapter class:**

```
public class MarketFeedRecyclerAdapter extends LoadingRowRecyclerAdapter {

    private static final int VIEW_TYPE_MARKET_FEED = 0;
    private static final int VIEW_TYPE_AD = 1;

    private final Context context;
    private final List<Feed> feedItems;
    private final ImageLoader feedItemImageLoader;
    private FeedItemClickListener feedItemClickListener;

    private boolean isLongPressed = false;
    public MarketFeedRecyclerAdapter(Context context, List<Feed> feedItems, ImageLoader feedItemImageLoader, List<Feed> adItems) {
        this.context = context;
        this.feedItems = feedItems;
        this.feedItemImageLoader = feedItemImageLoader;
        this.feedItems.addAll(adItems);
    }

    @Override
    public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        switch (viewType) {
            case VIEW_TYPE_MARKET_FEED:
                return new MarketFeedViewHolder(new FeedItemView(context));
            case VIEW_TYPE_AD:
                return new AdViewHolder(new MarketFeedAdItemView(context));
        }
        return super.onCreateViewHolder(parent, viewType);
    }

    // Differentiate between feedItem views and nativeAds
    @Override
    public int getViewType(int position) {
        int viewType = VIEW_TYPE_MARKET_FEED;
        if ((position % 25 == 0)) {
            viewType = VIEW_TYPE_AD;
        }
        return viewType;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int position) {
        if (getViewType(position) == VIEW_TYPE_MARKET_FEED) {
                bindMarketFeedItemView((MarketFeedViewHolder) viewHolder, position - position / 6);
        }  else {
            bindAdItemView((AdViewHolder) viewHolder);
        }
    }

    // For Ad Objects
    private void bindAdItemView(AdViewHolder viewHolder) {

        showNativeAd(viewHolder);

    }

    private void bindMarketFeedItemView(MarketFeedViewHolder viewHolder, int position) {
        final FeedItemView feedItemView = viewHolder.feedItemView;
        final Feed feedDesign = feedItems.get(position);

        // TODO we can probably conditionally show or hide these based on the type of feed item, same as in FeedActivitySingle
        feedItemView.showOrHideEditButton(false);
        feedItemView.showOrHideBuyButton(true);
        feedItemView.showOrHideFlipButton(feedDesign.getDesign().getCompressedBackImage() != null);
        feedItemView.showOrHidePriceText(true);

        // Set the results into TextViews
        feedItemView.setProductPriceText(String.valueOf(feedDesign.getDesign().getPrice()));
        feedItemView.setDownloadsText(String.valueOf(feedDesign.getDesign().getDownloadCount()));
        feedItemView.setLikesText(String.valueOf(feedDesign.getDesign().getLikesCount()));
        feedItemView.setUsernameText(feedDesign.getDesign().getAuthor().getUsername());
        feedItemView.setTimestampText(feedDesign.getTimestampText());
        feedItemView.getSaveImage().setImageResource(feedDesign.isInPersonalGallery() ? R.drawable.ic_action_saved : R.drawable.ic_not_saved);
        feedItemView.getLikeImage().setImageResource(feedDesign.isLiked() ? R.drawable.ic_action_like_feed_full : R.drawable.ic_action_like_feed);

        feedItemView.getTrashImage().setVisibility(ParseHelper.isCurrentUser(feedDesign.getDesign().getAuthor().getObjectId()) ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE);
        feedItemView.getFeedSocialShareImage().setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        switch(feedDesign.getDisplayedSide()) {
            case FRONT:
                feedItemImageLoader.DisplayImage(feedDesign.getDesign().getCompressedImage().getUrl(), feedItemView.getImage(), feedItemView.getProgressBar());
                break;
            case BACK:
                feedItemImageLoader.DisplayImage(feedDesign.getDesign().getCompressedBackImage().getUrl(), feedItemView.getImage(), feedItemView.getProgressBar());
                break;
        }

        if(feedDesign.getDesign().getAuthor().getProfilePicture() != null) {
            feedItemImageLoader.DisplayImage(feedDesign.getDesign().getAuthor().getProfilePicture().getUrl(), feedItemView.getProfilePicture(), null); // TODO should this use profilePictureFileCache?
        } else {
            viewHolder.feedItemView.getProfilePicture().setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_anonymous);
        }

        SetCommentViews(feedItemView, feedDesign.getComments());
        SetClickListeners(feedItemView, feedDesign, position);
    }

    @Override
    protected int getContentDataSize() {
        return feedItems.size();
    }

class MarketFeedViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    FeedItemView feedItemView;

    public MarketFeedViewHolder(FeedItemView view) {
        super(view);
        this.feedItemView = view;
    }
}

class AdViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    MarketFeedAdItemView adItemView;

    public AdViewHolder(MarketFeedAdItemView view) {
        super(view);
        this.adItemView = view;
    }

}

    private NativeAd nativeAd;
    private AdChoicesView adChoicesView;

    private void showNativeAd(AdViewHolder viewHolder){
        AdSettings.addTestDevice("a6ffb7bec7af13f768f033dbfea042df");
        nativeAd = new NativeAd(context, "846223392142435_1025413774223395");
        nativeAd.setAdListener(new AdListener() {

            @Override
            public void onError(Ad ad, AdError adError) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onAdLoaded(Ad ad) {

                final MarketFeedAdItemView adItemView = viewHolder.adItemView;

                // Setting the Text
                adItemView.nativeAdSocialContext.setText(nativeAd.getAdSocialContext());
                adItemView.nativeAdCallToAction.setText(nativeAd.getAdCallToAction());
                adItemView.nativeAdTitle.setText(nativeAd.getAdTitle());
                adItemView.nativeAdBody.setText(nativeAd.getAdBody());

                // Downloading and setting the ad icon
                NativeAd.Image adIcon = nativeAd.getAdIcon();
                NativeAd.downloadAndDisplayImage(adIcon, adItemView.nativeAdIcon);

                // Download and setting the cover image
                /*NativeAd.Image adCoverImage = nativeAd.getAdCoverImage();*/
                adItemView.nativeAdMedia.setNativeAd(nativeAd);

                // Add adChoices icon
                if (adChoicesView == null) {
                    adChoicesView = new AdChoicesView(context, nativeAd, true);
                    adItemView.addView(adChoicesView, 0);
                }

                nativeAd.registerViewForInteraction(adItemView);

            }

            @Override
            public void onAdClicked(Ad ad) {

            }
        });

        nativeAd.loadAd();
    }
}
```

**My RecyclerAdapter extends the following class, which helps with loading more feedItems:**

```
public abstract class LoadingRowRecyclerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {

    public static final int ROW_VIEW_TYPE_LOADING = 72398; // obscure number
    private boolean mContainsLoadingRow;

    protected abstract int getContentDataSize();

    protected abstract int getViewType(int position);

    @Override
    public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        switch (viewType) {
            case ROW_VIEW_TYPE_LOADING:
                return new LoadingViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.loading_row, parent, false));
        }

        throw new IllegalArgumentException("viewType is not ROW_VIEW_TYPE_LOADING. You must handle all other values of viewType (defined by getViewType) before calling super.");
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        // empty
    }

    @Override
    public final int getItemCount() {
        return mContainsLoadingRow ? (getContentDataSize() + 1) : getContentDataSize();
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        return (position == getContentDataSize()) ? ROW_VIEW_TYPE_LOADING : getViewType(position);
    }

    /**
     * Sets a boolean which is used by getItemCount and in turn getItemViewType to determine which view type the row should be (loading view vs. other view).
     * Should only be called when there is more results to load in an upcoming api request (determined by calling fragment).
     */
    public void toggleLoadingRowOn() {
        mContainsLoadingRow = true;
    }

    /**
     * Checks to see if a loading row exists by checking an instance boolean and removes the row / clears the boolean.
     * This helps to 'replace' a loading row with a different row.
     */
    public void toggleLoadingRowOff() {
        if (mContainsLoadingRow) {
            mContainsLoadingRow = false;

            // removes the loading row explicitly instead of allowing it to be 'pushed' down when new user suggestion rows are added.
            // this is only required to maintain consistency with the rest of the app.
            int position = getContentDataSize();
            if (position >= 0) {
                notifyItemRemoved(position);
            }
        }
    }

    protected class LoadingViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        public LoadingViewHolder(View v) {
            super(v);
        }
    }
}
```

**Finally, the class which determines the threshold for loading more items:**

```
public abstract class EndlessRecyclerOnScrollListener extends RecyclerView.OnScrollListener {

    private static final int VISIBLE_THRESHOLD = 5; // The minimum amount of items to have below your current scroll position before loading more
    private LinearLayoutManager mLinearLayoutManager;

    public abstract void onLoadMore();

    public EndlessRecyclerOnScrollListener(LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager) {
        this.mLinearLayoutManager = linearLayoutManager;
    }

    @Override
    public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
        super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);

        int totalItemCount = mLinearLayoutManager.getItemCount();
        int firstVisibleItem = mLinearLayoutManager.findFirstVisibleItemPosition();
        int visibleItemCount = recyclerView.getChildCount();

        int lastItemVisible = firstVisibleItem + visibleItemCount;

        // once the last visible item is within VISIBLE_THRESHOLD from the bottom, we want to load more
        if ((totalItemCount - lastItemVisible) <= VISIBLE_THRESHOLD) {
            onLoadMore();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem in your code is there:

```
@Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int position) {
        if (getViewType(position) == VIEW_TYPE_MARKET_FEED) {
                bindMarketFeedItemView((MarketFeedViewHolder) viewHolder, position - position / 6);
        }  else {
            bindAdItemView((AdViewHolder) viewHolder);
        }
    }
```

You are checking for current row viewType (and that's good), but you can actually have 3 possible viewType: *market*, *ad* and *loading*.

So when this

```
@Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        return (position == getContentDataSize()) ? ROW_VIEW_TYPE_LOADING : getViewType(position);
    }
```

return *ROW_VIEW_TYPE_LOADING* you are casting a `LoadingViewHolder` to `AdViewHolder`.

That cause the `ClassCastException`.

For solving that just change the `onBindViewHolder` method to either include all three possible view types or use an `else if` instead of `else`.

Hope this helps

Comment: I added ``else if (getItemViewType(position) == VIEW_TYPE_AD) {`` to my ``onBindViewHolder`` method, but I get the identical exception, so unfortunately this doesn't solve the problem. Thanks either way.

Comment: I think that in the first `if` you should use `getItemViewType` and not `getViewType` since the former is more generic and includes the latter. Let me know if this helps

Comment: Hmm. No luck. I'm getting the same exception.

Comment: Try placing some logs around to check which `if` branch is executed. The problem is: you are creating some view types and when RecyclerView call binding methods view type is different. So the problem is in `onBindViewHolder` or `onCreateViewHolder`. Probably it's an edge case too

Comment: ``Log.w(getClass().toString(), "VIEW_TYPE_AD");`` I see that the Ad view holder is executed just prior to the exception, but that's just what the stack trace says I guess. It's trying to show a loading row but it's showing an ad row instead. Not sure what to make of it.

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce your issue in a test project. I copied your classes, removed the actual binding (`bindMarketFeedItemView` and `bindAdItemView`) and replaced them with stub text. It's working just fine, no cast exception at all

Comment: I guess we can't rule out that removing the bindings doesn't fix the problem. Unfortunately, I need the bindings to stay. In the context of my problem, I'm unable to solve it with your provided solution.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/116675/discussion-between-rsella-and-bluemunch).

Comment: I had to change getItemViewType to getViewType in my onBindViewHolder so that it properly refers to LoadingRowRecyclerAdapter's getItemViewType method.